# How do I run a python program in Visual Studio Code with input from sys.argv[1]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
import sys

gallons = int(sys.argv[1])
litre = gallons * 3.785411784
litre = round(litre,3)
print(gallons, "gallon(US) is equal to", litre, "litre")
```

For example if I were to run this code in windows cmd I would type:
`python "C:\Users\public\Desktop\assign2-6.py" 15`

It would take 15 as the input and convert 15 into litre and return the output.
How would I run this code in  Visual Studio Code/Pycharm so I would not have to manually type the file location?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Dump VSC and use a proper (non-MS) IDE. 2) Build and argparser and implement that into your project.  :-)

Comment: @S3DEV, curious, what's wrong with VSC (or MS IDEs in general)?

Comment: Why would one use an MS product for open-souce development?  What has MS (ever) contributed to the OS world?  Two very different ideologies.

Comment: @S3DEV, "what has MS ever contributed to the OS world?" How about [VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)? Regardless of what you think of MS's opensource contributions, using only opensource tools for opensource development sounds somewhat impossible to me, because that would preclude people from using a Windows / Mac computer, which is what quite a lot of people use.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - “because that would preclude people from using a Windows / Mac computer”.  And wouldn’t that be a great world ...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

***Your Solution:***
You could open the VSCode Terminal and change its directory to the 
file parent directory using:
`cd C:\Users\public\Desktop`
and then everytime just run the
command `python assign2-6.py 15`.
Or you could just take the input while the program runs instead of `sys.argv[1]`